# Lazy initialization with repository

Tags: android, kotlin

I checked out the [Android Sunflower](https://github.com/android/sunflower) best practices app. And i kinda struggle to understand why the initialization of the [PlantDetailsViewModel](https://github.com/android/sunflower/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/sunflower/viewmodels/PlantDetailViewModel.kt) is working.
The class is defined as follows

```
class PlantDetailViewModel @AssistedInject constructor(
    plantRepository: PlantRepository,
    private val gardenPlantingRepository: GardenPlantingRepository,
    @Assisted private val plantId: String
) : ViewModel() {
    
val isPlanted = gardenPlantingRepository.isPlanted(plantId)
val plant = plantRepository.getPlant(plantId)
        
    ....

@AssistedInject.Factory
interface AssistedFactory {
    fun create(plantId: String): PlantDetailViewModel
}

companion object {
    fun provideFactory(
        assistedFactory: AssistedFactory,
        plantId: String
    ): ViewModelProvider.Factory = object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            return assistedFactory.create(plantId) as T
        }
    }
}
```

}

here the `gardenPlantingRepository` and `plantRepository` give access to a **Room Database**.
I wonder that this works because normally it is not possible to access a room database on the main thread. The Viemodel is used in the [PlantDetailFragment](https://github.com/android/sunflower/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/sunflower/PlantDetailFragment.kt) and lazy initialized.

```
@Inject
lateinit var plantDetailViewModelFactory: PlantDetailViewModel.AssistedFactory

private val plantDetailViewModel: PlantDetailViewModel by viewModels {
    PlantDetailViewModel.provideFactory(
        plantDetailViewModelFactory,
        args.plantId
    )
}
```

if i try something that is quite the same i always get the problem that it is not possible to access the database on the main thread. so i tried to init my variables in the `init` function with a `coroutine` and `Dispatchers.IO` but the problem with this is that when i access member variables of my viewmodel they are not initialized. so how is the behaviour of the sunflower app reproducible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repository uses Dao methods that return LiveData

> The Room persistence library supports observable queries, which return LiveData objects. Observable queries are written as part of a Database Access Object (DAO).
>
> Room generates all the necessary code to update the LiveData object when a database is updated. The generated code runs the query asynchronously on a background thread when needed. This pattern is useful for keeping the data displayed in a UI in sync with the data stored in a database.
> https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#use_livedata_with_room

If you want to use coroutines then you should create and expose `LiveData` in your `ViewModel`

```
class ViewModel(
    val repository: Repository
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _liveData = MutableLiveData<SomeType>()
    val liveData: LiveData<SomeType> get() = _liveData

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            _liveData.postValue(repository.getSomeData())
        }
    }

}
```

Then you should observe this liveData in your activity / fragment

Comment: does this mean that as long my room query returns LiveData it can be executed from the main thread?

Comment: @tscheppe yes,  you also can use suspend functions / Flow in Dao and execute them from the Main dispatcher